# Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program" error when run WPF application that uses the RenderTargetBitmap class

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv, bitmap, azure-cognitive-services

Currently, Working on project for detect face from Live Video. I had used MS cognitive service face api for detect face and opencvsharp for streaming live video. Now I need to draw a face rectangle on live video screen. For this I had override the frame with draw content(whatever want).
    This is working on some pc while gives error in some another machine although they are same configuration. Can you please suggest what I am wrong there:

```
 private static BitmapSource DrawOverlay(BitmapSource baseImage, Action<DrawingContext, double> drawAction)
    {
        double annotationScale = baseImage.PixelHeight / 320;

        DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
        DrawingContext drawingContext = visual.RenderOpen();

        drawingContext.DrawImage(baseImage, new Rect(0, 0, baseImage.Width, baseImage.Height));

        drawAction(drawingContext, annotationScale);

        drawingContext.Close();

        RenderTargetBitmap outputBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
            baseImage.PixelWidth, baseImage.PixelHeight,
            baseImage.DpiX, baseImage.DpiY, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        outputBitmap.Render(visual);

        return outputBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure all windows updates are installed on PC.

Comment: Yes, its already

Comment: Are you building on each PC or copying executable to each machine?  You need to have same version of Net Library on each machine if youi are copying executable directly from build PC to other machines.  Best way of installing software is to menu Build : Publish and use CD option (you don't need a CD and can use any drive for build).  Then install SETUP folder on other PCs like any commercial purchased software.  The SETUP will install any dll upgrades that are different in the PCs.

Comment: I am running it using visual studio on both machines. The only difference is resolution of camera. System A has 1 mega pixel camera where I am getting memory error. However the resolution of camera on system B is less than 1 mega pixel. It works fine on system B.